# how to get Twitter username from a tweet- PYTHON

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am new at tweepy, I was able to fetch data from twitter with following script :

```
    import tweepy
    from tweepy import OAuthHandler 
    access_token="---------" 
    access_token_secret="----------" 
    consumer_key="---------" 
    consumer_secret="-------"    
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret) 
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)    
    api = tweepy.API(auth)    
    public_tweets = api.home_timeline()    
    print("public_tweets.text")
```

now want to fetch the username of the twitting person as well fetched tweets as

example:

"USERNAME": " --------------TWEET----------"

Thank You in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public_tweets = api.home_timeline()
for tweet in public_tweets:
    print('From :', tweet.user.screen_name, ', Text :', tweet.text)
```